# Contain the \ in CN name in AD

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, system

I have a big problem with AD windows server.
Now I am trying to create AD account by using powershell script and python script.
When I create AD account with powershell script, it include `\` behind of CN name.

For example, I created `TEAM3` account in AD with powershell script. In the `distinguishedName` in Attribute editor in AD, the CN name is show like this `CN=TEAM3\.OU=User....` and so on.

I use the csv file to store the AD account `Username,Password,FirstName,DisplayName,UPN,LastName` and Powershell script will execute the account creation from csv file.

Let me provide my code,
by the way, I am not powershell expert, I just trying and those code I reference from CHATGPT.
I Really Appreciate it.
Thanks

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 $userDetails = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

 

    # Establish a connection to the domain controller
    #$credential = Get-Credential

    #Import-PSSession -Session $session -Module ActiveDirectory

    foreach ($user in $userDetails) {
       # Set the user properties
       $username = $user.Username
       $firstname = $user.FirstName
       $lastname = $user.LastName
       $displayname = $user.DisplayName
       $upn = $user.UPN
       $mypassword = $user.Password
    
        # Prompt for password
        #$password = Read-Host "Enter password for user '$username'" -AsSecureString
        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $mypassword -AsPlainText -Force
    
        # Create the user account
        $newUser = New-ADUser -SamAccountName $username -UserPrincipalName $upn -GivenName $firstname -        Surname $lastname -DisplayName $displayname -Name "$firstname $lastname" -AccountPassword $password -  Enabled $true -Path $ou
    
        $newUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $username

        Write-Host "New User: $($newUser.SamAccountName)"
        # Set additional user properties if needed
        # Set-ADUser -Identity $newUser -Description "Some description"
        # Set-ADUser -Identity $newUser -Office "Some office"
        # Add the user to a specific group
        $group = "SVP Users"  # Replace with the name of the group you want to add the user to
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $newUser
        Write-Host "User account created: $username"
}

# Remove the session after the loop is completed
#Remove-PSSession $session
```

I want to remove that `\` from CN in AD.

Comment: In your CSV do you have `Username` ending with a `.` ?

Comment: What is the full distinguished name of the new object? Check  `$newUser.DistinguishedName` after creation

Comment: As aside, remove the illegal spaces between the hyphen and the parameter names

Comment: Show us the first 3 or 4 lines from your input csv file. Use the [edit] link underneath your question and paste it in there. By the way, `New-ADUser` only returns the newly created object when the `PassThru` parameter is specified. Also, have a look at [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to help make the code readable/maintainable. If you search SO, there are many, MANY good examples on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, I can solve it. I update my script as to remove / in username. Thus, now it is okay. The main reason is I just need to rename the account created name.